# Solr: Check if a document exists without retrieving the document

Tags: php, solr, nosql

I need to find out if a document exists but the documents saved in the Solr server are pretty big so if I do a classic search to retrieve the document with a specified `id` and the document is returned it takes too much time to process.
Is there a possibility to return for example the number of matching documents without retrieving the actual documents ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You can set rows=0 when submitting a query, execute it.  No actual documents are returned.

In the response, you can read the numFound attribute from response.  If numFound=1 (since this is for ID), then the document is found.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the fl parameter to only return the desired fields from the documents.